# Adding Group totals to a different section of an SSRS report

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Sample Data:

`id    dept    section   item    amount
 1      a         z       12       2
 2      a         y       13       3
 3      b         z       14       3
 4      a         x       15       10`

I have an SSRS report that has totals per section, so section x shows a total of 10, y 3, and z 5.  What I'm looking to do is have a dept total (a = 15 and b = 3), but maybe in a subreport at the top, or even the end if need be.  It fairly straight forward in Crystal, but I just cannot figure this out in SSRS.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sub report for this, simply add a row group just prior to the "section" row group and base it on the field "dept".

However, the data you posted above is not laid out in a way that is intuitive of what you are trying to do. You will need to order by your group fields with repeating values or roll-up your data for this to make any sense at all.